# How to include nohup inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, nohup

I have a large script called **mandacalc** which I want to always run with the **nohup** command. If I call it from the command line as:

```
nohup mandacalc &
```

everything runs swiftly. But, if I try to include **nohup** inside my command, so I don't need to type it everytime I execute it, I get an error message.

So far I tried these options:

```
nohup (
command1
....
commandn
exit 0
)
```

and also:

```
nohup bash -c "
command1
....
commandn
exit 0
" # and also with single quotes.
```

So far I only get error messages complaining about the implementation of the **nohup** command, or about other quotes used inside the script.

cheers.

Comment: do you need to give the full path to nohup possibly?  `which nohup`

Answer (score 26):

Try putting this at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    -d|--daemon)
        $0 < /dev/null &> /dev/null & disown
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

# do stuff here
```

If you now start your script with `--daemon` as an argument, it will restart itself detached from your current shell.

You can still run your script "in the foreground" by starting it without this option.

Comment: Isn't this limited only to cases where the script has no arguments?

Comment: @YanFoto You are correct. In order to pass all arguments, the line should be changed to `$0 "$@" < /dev/null &> /dev/null & disown`.

Comment: @mattalxndr : not really : first you should parse the arguments and take out the "--daemon" or you'll end up with a fork loop.

Comment: you should do: `for arg in "$@"; do if [ "$arg" = "-d" ] || [ "$arg" = "-daemon" ]; then start_as_daemon="true" ; else other_args+=( "$arg" ) ; fi ; if [ "$start_as_daemon" = "true" ]; then $0 "${other_args[@]}" </dev/null >&/dev/null & disown ; exit 0 ; fi`

Answer (score 6):

Create an alias of the same name in your bash (or preferred shell) startup file:

```sh
alias mandacalc="nohup mandacalc &"
```

Answer (score 6):

Just put `trap '' HUP` on the beggining of your script.

Also if it creates child process `someCommand&` you will have to change them to `nohup someCommand&` to work properly... I have been researching this for a long time and only the combination of these two (the trap and nohup) works on my specific script where xterm closes too fast.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thank you kind stranger!

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just make a script containing `nohup ./original_script` ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice answer here: http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/can-a-script-nohup-itself/498135

```
#!/bin/bash

### make sure that the script is called with `nohup nice ...`
if [ "$1" != "calling_myself" ]
then
    # this script has *not* been called recursively by itself
    datestamp=$(date +%F | tr -d -)
    nohup_out=nohup-$datestamp.out
    nohup nice "$0" "calling_myself" "$@" > $nohup_out &
    sleep 1
    tail -f $nohup_out
    exit
else
    # this script has been called recursively by itself
    shift # remove the termination condition flag in $1
fi

### the rest of the script goes here
. . . . .
```

Answer (score -1):

the best way to handle this is to use `$()`

```
nohup $( command1, command2 ...) &
```

`nohup` is expecting one command and in that way You're able to execute multiple commands with one `nohup`

Comment: I don't think this works. The `$()` syntax will run some command(s) and include their output *before* invoking `nohup`.