# Call a function using nohup

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, nohup

I am trying to call a function using `nohup` like this:

```
function1(){
    while true 
    do
        echo "function1"
        sleep 1
    done
}

nohup function1 & 
# ...... some other code
```

but may be the function isn't seen by `nohup` and I get this error:

```
nohup: failed to run command `function1' : No such file or dictionary
```

I don't want to create new sh file for my function. How can I fix this?

Comment: nohup requires as an argument a file (what the error message clearly says) not a function. But what you can do is: modify the above script so that it accepts a new argument (e.g. "--nohup"), when this argument is passed just invoke `function1` and replace `nohup function1 &` with `nohup $0 --nohup &` in your script

Comment: You mean I have to use `nohup` in the function? I am confused about the `--nohup`  option calling the function!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include nohup inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168781/how-to-include-nohup-inside-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 34):

Another solution:

```
function background {
    echo TEST
}
export -f background 

nohup bash -c background &
```

Comment: dont forget quotes around your function call if you're passing in arguments: `nohup bash -c 'background "hello there"' &` if your func is `echo "$1"`

Comment: `export: -f: unknown option`

Answer (score 10):

`nohup` applies to commands and not to script functions.

For example, the script (say func.sh) that contains function1() should call the function-:

```
function1(){
    while true 
    do
        echo "function1"
        sleep 1
    done

}

function1
```

Now call the script func.sh with `nohup` in the background-:

```
nohup ./func.sh &
```

If you need to disable the hangup signal from within the script use the shell built-in `trap`. The example ignores SIGHUP but can be used to ignore others (e.g. SIGINT).

```
trap "" HUP   # script will ignore HANGUP signal
```

Comment: Is there anyway to apply nohup on the functions? I prefer not to use several sh files.

Comment: No unfortunately. What you could do is keep common functions in a one script then source it; that would reduce the script count.

Comment: There is the trap command which can be used to trap signals - see my edited answer. This may suit your requirements.

Answer (score 8):

I find a working solution for me - define the function in a file (e.g. `.functions`) then run the function with nohup:

`nohup bash -c "source .functions; function1" &`

Tested on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: `nohup bash -c 'source .functions"arg1"' &` --> `bash: .functions: No such file or directory` even though functions was defined as a function in the same shell script

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using nohup, which is tailored for files, you can implement the same result like this:

```
(trap '' HUP INT
 while true
 do
   echo "function1"
   sleep 1
 done
) </dev/null 2>&1 1>nohup.out &
```

As I tend to launch these processes from a parent script and the parent script may do other work if the parent process is interrupted I want the child process to ignore the INT signal and keep on running.

Comment: I didn't know about this trick. Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: Essentially `trap` catches the SIGHUP and SIGINT signals and ignores them allowing us to create an isolated sub-shell for our function to run.A more detailed explanation is here: https://gist.github.com/bluekezza/e511f3f4429939a0f9ecb6447099b3dc

Comment: I think the redirection order here is wrong. `</dev/null 2>&1 1>nohup.out` points stderr to `/dev/tty` and *then* points stdout to `nohup.out`. The result is that error output is now going to stdout. You want `</dev/null 1>nohup.out 2>&1` which redirects both stderr and stdout to `nohup.out`.

Answer (score 6):

Since `nohup` must be supplied with a filename not a function as a workaround this is what can be done:

```
function1(){
    while true 
    do
        echo "function1"
        sleep 1
    done

}

echo "$@" | grep -q -- "--nohup" && function1 || nohup $0 "$@" --nohup &
```

So when this script gets called with the current arguments:

- `` `echo "$@" | grep -q -- "--nohup" `` will return an error status so
- `nohup $0 "$@" --nohup &` will be invoked, which will invoke this script passing the current arguments and a new argument `--nohup`

And when this script is called with argument `--nohup`

- `` `echo "$@" | grep -q -- "--nohup" `` will return with zero status (success) so
- `function1` will be invoked

Answer (score 3):

Yes ! It is possible however tricky, and strictly bash > v2 compatible :

```
function1(){ local msg=${*:-function1}; echo msg=$msg; }
nohup -- sh -c "$(typeset -f function1); function1 MESSAGE" >nohup.log 2>&1 0</dev/null &
```

And don't forget "typeset" is bash deprecated in favor of "declare" (though I don't entirely agree with this).

Answer (score 1):

About:

```
function background {
     echo TEST 
} 
export -f background 

nohup bash -c background &
```

For people encountering the issue:

```
export: -f: unknown option –
```

Be sure to be in **bash** or **csh**, because "export -f" is usually not recognized in e.g. **ksh**

Sorry, not yet the reputation to comment the *IceTea* answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

try edit `nohup function1 &` to this

> ```
> function1=$(function1)
> nohup $function1 --nohup &
> ```