# How to use `while true` with nohup?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nohup

I would like to run a script on remote Ubuntu PC (AWS).

```
while true; do timeout 1h python worker.py --log-level=ERROR; done
```

works well, but when I add `nohup`:

```
nohup while true; do timeout 1h python worker.py --log-level=ERROR; done &
```

it returns me the error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`.

What is the right syntax?

Comment: `nohup` works on executables, not shell functions/loops (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435629/linux-shell-script-call-a-function-by-nohup)) so you can't use it with a naked `while`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
nohup bash -c 'while true; do timeout 1h python worker.py --log-level=ERROR; done'
```