# Disown a function from a script?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I'm not sure this is really possible, but maybe someone has some suggestion on how I can do something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dissed() {
    for i in {1..10}
    do
        sleep 5
        echo "$(date)"
    done
}

/usr/bin/screen -S disowned -d -m dissed & disown -h; 

screen -ls

echo "done."
```

Of course this doesn't work, since I assume the function gets killed when the script ends. I know it works when I substitute an actual `.sh` file where the "dissed" function gets called, but this is what I want to avoid.

Is there some way to disown a function or subscript located in the parent?

Comment: Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202797/3227693

Answer (score 0):

To detach a process from a bash script:

nohup ./process &
If you stop your bash script with SIGINT for instance, the process won't be bothered and will continue to execute normally. stdout & stderr will be redirected to a file: nohup.out.

If you wish to execute a detached command while being able to see the output in the terminal, then use tail:

TEMP_LOG_FILE=tmp.log

> "$TEMP_LOG_FILE"
>   nohup ./process &> "$TEMP_LOG_FILE" & tail -f "$TEMP_LOG_FILE" &

Comment: This calls another script file though doesn't it?