# Run shell script with arguments using nohup

Tags: shell, arguments, nohup

I need to do remote login to a server and run a shell script with arguments in the background using `nohup`. But I am getting an error. Am I missing anything in syntax?

**Mycode:**

```
ssh -t -t user@servername nohup /path/myscript.sh argument1 argument2 & > /path/myscrip_logfile.log
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid null command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include nohup inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168781/how-to-include-nohup-inside-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 3):

nohup accepts arguments like you have supplied, the "& >" should be "&>" and the whole command should be put in quotes as otherwise i think you are redirecting the stdout of the ssh command so try this:

```
ssh -t -t user@servername "nohup /path/myscript.sh argument1 argument2 &> /path/myscrip_logfile.log"
```

Comment: I changed it as suggested, but getting the same error still. Do we need to give "&" at the end of logfile name?

Comment: There should not be a need but you can try that. Are you sure the script you are running doesn't generate that error?