# Scripts with nohup inside don't exit correctly

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

We have script which do some processing and triggers a job in background using nohup. When we schedule this script from Oracle OEM (or it can be any scheduler job), i see the following error and show status as failed but the script actually finished without issue. How to exit the script correctly when backup ground job is started with nohup?

```
Remote operation finished but process did not close its stdout/stderr
```

### file: test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some processing
...
nohup ./start.sh 2000 &

# end of the script
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include nohup inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168781/how-to-include-nohup-inside-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By executing `start.sh` in this manner you are allowing it to claim partial ownership of `test.sh`'s output file descriptors (`stdout`/`stderr`).  So whereas when *most* bash scripts exit, their file descriptors are closed for them (by the operating system), `test.sh`'s file descriptors cannot be closed because `start.sh` still has a claim to them.

The solution is to not let `start.sh` claim the same output file descriptors as `test.sh` is using.  If you don't care about its output, you can launch it like this:

```
nohup ./start.sh 2000 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

which tells the new process to send both its stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.  If you do care about its output, then just capture it somewhere more meaningful:

```
nohup ./start.sh 2000 1>/path/to/stdout.txt 2>/path/to/stderr.txt &
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same error after completion of the job.#Startup MMLE services,
$ADMIN_SCRIPTS_HOME/wmlke.sh start 10218
$ADMIN_SCRIPTS_HOME/wmlke.sh start 10220
$ADMIN_SCRIPTS_HOME/wmlke.sh start 10222
nohup $ADMIN_SCRIPTS_HOME/wmlke.sh start_dispatcher 10809 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &

Comment: You accepted my answer.  Does that mean that it ended up working for you?  Or are you still having issues?

Comment: Works now after adding output file descriptors to other commands as well.

Comment: worked for me. thanks. spent like a whole day trying to find out why the script I'm executing remotely hangs.