# not able to execute next statement in a shell script after running a java jar app using nohup

Tags: java, shell, ssh, sh, nohup

Not able to execute other instruction after if I am running a java jar file (which is present on another host) from my shell script.I tried using nohup but still not able to exit.
following is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 sshpass -p "${array[1]}" ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ${array[0]}@${array[2]} "cd ${array[3]} &&  echo -ne '\n' | nohup java -jar myapp.jar";
#some other instructions
echo "next statement"
```

already tried [Scripts with nohup inside don't exit correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709790/scripts-with-nohup-inside-dont-exit-correctly) but it doesn't worked.

Comment: You call nohup and use '&'   .  Shouldn't you remove the '&'?

Comment: I removed  '&', still it is not working

Comment: can you post the logs if there are any, try running the script with set -x option which might open up more errors to look into.

Comment: there is no error. the java application is running perfectly but the problem is the next statement in my script is not executing after that.

Comment: basically the control is not coming back to my script

Comment: why are you doing piping ?

Comment: `echo -ne '\n'` is *exactly* equivalent to `echo` with no options or arguments (and POSIX-compliant to boot).

Comment: *Without* `&`, `ssh` will wait for the command to complete before exiting itself. I'm wondering if the combination of `sshpass`, `ssh`, and the pipe interact in such a way as to break something. I'd start by replacing `sshpass` with public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
sshpass -p pass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xyz@hostname 'cd dir; nohup java -jar myapp.jar'
```

Try this with replacing the values appropriately

Comment: I am already passing these values in the array. and it is working perfectly, the java myapp.jar is running using nohup. the only issue is I am not able to get the control back into my script and not able to execute next statement in the shell script.

Comment: then try redirecting the nohup output to a file and you should get back the control to your shell script.