# How to run Jupyter Lab on every startup on amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jupyter-lab, tmux

I have already tried user-data method and rc.local methods but none are working. I am not a pro so would like some help on this.

These are the 3 commands i want to run on every startup of ec2 instance:

1. tmux (start a tmux session so i dont loose the data when connection resets)
2. source pyenv/bin/activate (Activate the venv)
3. jupyter-lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root (run the jupyter lab)

I'm using a ubuntu ec2 instance btw. Thanks in advance.

If i can acheieve this using nohup instead of tmux i'd be willing to that as well.

I wasn't able to find a solution anywhere so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that user-data by default runs only on launch of a new instance? If you want to make it run on every startup, you need to check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/. Also, you haven't provided any info on what errors etc do you get if you have already configured user data to run on each reboot/restart.

Comment: Yes i have already tried the method in this help page but it doesn't work. I cant see any error message, nothing in logs either @Riz

Comment: ok..the second question. Why do you think you need tmux? It's not like you login to this node from a remote shell and launch it. you can just do souce and jupyter and that's it. No need for tmux

Comment: i used to directly run the jupyter notebook command and it used to loose its connection after a while (about 1 or 2 hours). But if i run it in tmux, the jupyternotebook would run till i shutdown the ec2 instance.

My end goal is to run my jupyterlab in my venv at every startup automatically. @Riz

Comment: You can add `#!/bin/bash -xe
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1` before tmux command and then check the logs in `/var/log/user-data.log` or if you want, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168781/how-to-include-nohup-inside-a-bash-script to use `nohup`.